# Autohotkey : Wildcard ahk_class match

Tags: autohotkey

I used winspy to grab an ahk_class for my autohotkey macro. Sometimes that application has 2+ ahk_classes associated with that program

Example:

```
HwndWrapper[program.exe;;1111-1111]
HwndWrapper[program.exe;;2222-2222]
```

How can I use winNotExist to simply just match both names? Or perhaps use a `||`, `OR` etc?

E.g.

```
F12::
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class "HwndWrapper.+"
    Run, AQ8.exe
GroupAdd, kjexplorers11, ahk_class "HwndWrapper.+" ;You have to make a new group for each application, don't use the same one for all of them!
if WinActive("ahk_exe AQ8.exe")
    GroupActivate, kjexplorers11, r
else
    WinActivate ahk_class ahk_class "HwndWrapper.+" ;you have to use WinActivatebottom if you didn't create a window group.
Return
```

Comment: Try [SetTitleMatchMode RegEx](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) OR create a group of those two ahk_classes using [GroupAdd](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm) and `IfWinNotExist, ahk_group my Group`.

Comment: I don't understand how settitlematchmode works. Documentation is lacking in good examples.How does it know to apply it to my ahk_class statements seen here?

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out. `SetTitleMatchMode, Regex`.

> This command affects the behavior of all windowing commands, e.g. WinExist and WinActivate

Then write some javascript-like regex statements as arguments.

The full list of window commands is on [AHK site](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm)

[image]

Script, revised

```
F12::
SetTitleMatchMode,RegEx
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class HwndWrapper.+
    Run, AQ8.exe
GroupAdd, kjexplorers11, ahk_class HwndWrapper.+ ;You have to make a new group for each application, don't use the same one for all of them!
if WinActive("ahk_exe AQ8.exe")
    GroupActivate, kjexplorers11, r
else
    WinActivate ahk_class ahk_class HwndWrapper.+ ;you have to use WinActivatebottom if you didn't create a window group.
Return
```

So now I can cycle through any application with more than 1 ahk_Class name. Example of what script does

[image]

Comment: I'd use "HwndWrapper_Group" instead of "kjexplorers11" to make clear that it concerns a windows group of that app or class.